# Writing logics other than validation inside validator method - rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, customvalidator

I have a scenario where I need to save the name of the associated record in the current object.

Consider that I have a JSON column and I have id of another table inside that JSON column.

Eg request:

```
users: {
  name: 'test', 
  additional_details: { another_table_id: 1}
}
```

What I have to do is to validate if another table has that **id**(request).

So I have added custom association in the user model,

```
 validates :validate_additional_table


 def validate_additional_table
    a_t = AnotherTable.where(id: additional_details['another_table_id']).first

    if a_t.present?
      additional_details.merge!(another_table_record_name: a_t.name) # Is it a good practice?
    else
      errors.add(:base, 'record is invalid')
    end

 end
```

I have added some other logic(check the comment in the above validator). Is that a best practice to have other than validation logics in validator?

Comment: I would say no. The validation should just validate. If you would like to persist other additional information there are other hooks for that such as `[before/after/around]_XXX`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about doing logics inside validations, but use

```
 AnotherTable.exists?(id: additional_details['another_table_id'])
```

instead of

```
a_t = AnotherTable.where(id: additional_details['another_table_id']).first

if a_t.present?
  additional_details.merge!(another_table_record_name: a_t.name) # Is it a good practice?
```

This would just get the count of records present in DB instead of loading all the data in memory. And add the name of Another table in after save callback